# How to return json value from php page to html page by ajax and how to show result on html page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I m validating email id in php and ajax, and want to return value from php page to html in JSON format.

I want to keep that return value in php variable for the further use.

I'm doing these all in codeigniter, and I want to show .gif image while my AJAX is processing. (Pre loader image)

AJAX/Javascript/jQuery:

```
function checkEmail(value_email_mobile) {
    if (value_email_mobile !== '') {
        //alert('te');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url_check_user_avail_status,
            data: "value_email_mobile=" + value_email_mobile,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
                //$('#psid').html("<img src='images/spacer.gif'>");
                // $('#stat').html(msg);
                //
                //$('#sid').sSelect({ddMaxHeight: '300px'});
            },
            error: function() {
                //alert('some error has occured...');
            },
            start: function() {
                //alert('ajax has been started...');    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP/Controller:

```
<?php

function check_email_or_mobile($param)
{
    $ci = CI();
    $value = $param['email_or_mobile'];
    $query = "SELECT user_email , mobile FROM tb_users WHERE user_email = '$value' or  mobile = '$value'";
    $query = $ci->db->query($query);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        if (is_numeric($value))
        {
            return $res = "This mobile number is not registerd";
        }
      else
        {
            return $res = "This Email id  is not registerd";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So.. what bit is not working?

Comment: make a array with key => value pair of data u want to return and then echo json_encode($array). on js msg.key to access the value.hope it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to give you an example on how it will work.

First off, (obviously) there must the a preloader image ready inside the document. This must be hidden initially.

Second, before triggering the AJAX request, show the loading animated GIF.

Third, after the request if successful. Hide the image again inside your `success:` block inside the `$.ajax()`.

Consider this example: [**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/M0eBn4)

PHP:

```
function check_email_or_mobile($param) {
    // your functions, processes, blah blah
    // lets say your processes and functions takes time
    // lets emulate the processing by using sleep :)
    sleep(3); // THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE! If your processing really takes time
    $data['message'] = 'Process finished!';

    // with regarding to storing, use sessions $_SESSION for further use
    $_SESSION['your_data'] = $data_that_you_got;

    echo json_encode($data); // use this function
    exit;
}

// just a simple trigger for that post request (only used in this example)
// you really dont need this since you will access it thru your url
// domain/controller/method
if(isset($_POST['request'])) {
    check_email_or_mobile(1);
}
```

HTML/jQuery/AJAX:

```
<!-- your animated loading image -->
<img src="http://i600.photobucket.com/albums/tt82/ugmhemhe/preloader.gif" id="loader" style="display: none;" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // before the request, show the GIF
    $('#loader').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: document.URL, // JUST A SAMPLE (url_check_user_avail_status)
        type: 'POST',
        data: {request: true},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        // data: "value_email_mobile=" + value_email_mobile,
        success: function(response) {
            // After a succesful response, hide the GIF
            $('#loader').fadeOut(); 
            alert(response.message);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

My assumption is, since this is just a simple email checking, this wont really take a chunk of time. The other way is to fake the loading process.

```
success: function(response) {
    // After a succesful response, hide the GIF

    // Fake the loading time, lets say 3 seconds
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#loader').fadeOut();
        alert(response.message);
    }, 3000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us know what part of your code is not working?

1) Check if the request flow is hitting the function checkEmail? PHP has inbuilt JSON converting utility `json_encode`. You could start using that.

2) If you want to store this on the server for further use, you could think about usage like

a) Storing it in Database (If really needed based on your requirements. Note: This is always expensive)
   b) Session - If you would want this info to be available for all the other users too.
   c) Or keep it in the memory like any of the caching mechanisms like memcache etc

3) For displaying the busy display,

```
// Before the below ajax call, show the busy display
$.ajax({
});
// After the ajax call, hide the busy display.
```

You could do this using JavaScript / JQuery on your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I remember using

JSON.parse(data)

to convert JSON ino a javascript object.

Jquery has its own JSON parser btw. Something like $.JSONParse(data)